# Trying to optimize a query that lists voters by voting activity

Tags: mysql, optimization, join, subquery

I'm building a query that lists voters from the `voters` table (1 million records) based on their activity in the `votes` table (7 million records). The criteria are as follows:

- General elections (GE) only happen once per year, and only GEs on or after 2004 should be counted.
- Of the previously mentioned GEs, only the ones in which 10% to 50% of voters have voted in should be counted.

Some less important info:

- The schema cannot be changed. It was presented to us as a fixed width text file, uploaded via a script, and is used for other purposes.
- Only the current list of active voters and their voting history is available. In my query below, I have included an equation that decreases the upper threshold by 10,000 voters every time the year decreases by 1. It's not perfect, but it seems to filter out the unwanted GEs while keeping the valid ones.

**For example, if between 100,000 and 500,000 voters voted in 2005, 2006, 2007, 2009, 2010, and 2011, then I want only the voters who voted on those years to be listed.**

[**mysqlfiddle is here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/feb32/5)

The schemas are as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `voters` (
  `CountyEMSID` varchar(9) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `LastName` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `FirstName` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `MiddleInitial` varchar(1) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `NameSuffix` varchar(4) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `HouseNumber` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `HouseNumberSuffix` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `ApartmentNumber` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `StreetName` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `City` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Zip` varchar(5) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `ZipCode4` varchar(4) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `MailingAddress1` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `MailingAddress2` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `MailingAddress3` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `MailingAddress4` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `DOBY` varchar(4) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `DOBM` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `DOBD` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Gender` varchar(1) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Party` varchar(3) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Other` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `ED` varchar(3) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `AD` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `CD` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `CO` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `SD` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `CC` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `JD` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `RegY` varchar(4) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `RegM` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `RegD` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Status` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `VoterType` varchar(1) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `StatusChangeY` varchar(4) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `StatusChangeM` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `StatusChangeD` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `LastVoted` varchar(4) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Telephone` varchar(12) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `County` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  KEY `districts` (`CountyEMSID`,`ED`,`AD`,`CD`,`CO`,`SD`,`CC`,`JD`),
  KEY `vsn` (`CountyEMSID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `votes` (
  `CountyEMSID` varchar(9) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `County` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `AD` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `ED` varchar(3) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Party` varchar(3) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `ElectionDateY` varchar(4) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `ElectionDateM` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `ElectionDateD` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `ElectionType` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `VoterType` varchar(1) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  KEY `CountyEMSID` (`CountyEMSID`),
  KEY `perfect` (`CountyEMSID`,`ElectionDateY`,`ElectionType`),
  KEY `CountyEMSID_2` (`CountyEMSID`,`ElectionDateY`,`ElectionType`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

So far, I have the following query that should just list the unique IDs (CountyEMSID) of the voters from the `votes` table. It works in mysqlfiddle, but hangs in phpmyadmin.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CountyEMSID
FROM `votes` 
WHERE ElectionDateY IN 
(
SELECT ElectionDateY
FROM `votes`
WHERE ElectionType = 'GE' 
AND ElectionDateY >= 2004 
GROUP BY ElectionDateY 
HAVING COUNT(*) < ((0.5 * (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `voters`)) - ((YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) - ElectionDateY) * 10000)) 
AND COUNT(*) > (0.1 * (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `voters`))
)
```

I would greatly appreciate any help with optimizing this query, and modifying it so it returns all the corresponding voter information from the `votes` table.

Comment: You really need to learn about normalization. Your `voters` table is horribly denormalized. 4 mailing addresses? 3 columns for DOB?

Comment: I know, it's a PITA, but I can't change the schema. I mentioned why in the post.

Comment: Agree with njk on the denormailzed data.. Anyway can you please show us what should be your expected results based on your fiddle? =)

Comment: @bonCodigo Based on the fiddle, the results should just be a list of unique CountyEMSIDs that correspond to the list of years returned by the subquery, the list of years which had general elections and a voter turnout of between 10% and 50%. Ideally, there should be between 100,000 and 500,000 records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL optimizes `in` clauses very poorly.  Basically, it reruns the subquery for every row processed.  You should move the calculations into the `from` clause.  Here is my attempt:

```
select distinct v.*
from votes v join
     (select electiondatey, count(*) as NumYVotes
      from votes v
      group by electiondatey
    ) ey
    on v.electiondatey = ev.electiondatey cross join
    (select count(*) as numvoters from voters) as const
where (NumYVotes < 0.5 * numvoters - year(now()) - ElectionDateY * 10000) and
      (NumYVotes > 0.1 * numvoters)
```

Note:  I haven't tested this so it probably has syntax errors.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, I can definitely use this information to get closer to what I need.